# How to send get variables in the url without kill previous sent get variables?

Tags: php, url, pagination, get, url-encoding

Hello guys am trying to make a pagination for my website so when I get items back from the database I count the array items then I divide them on 9 cause I want always to display 9 on the page or less , to this I use the pagination links and send a get variable called "page".

now the question is how can I do the same thing when searching I mean when a user enter search keyword and then hit enter the search box will then send another get variable called "search" the problem it removes the first one "page"

I want my pagination to work for regular cases but also to work in combination with search results.

like when someone hit search the pagination changes to cycle through the search results instead of the whole web-store items .

example: examine this url :

localhost/webstore/store.php?page=1

now when user search for football for example the link would then be like this:

localhost/webstore/store.php?search=football

I want it to be like this

localhost/webstore/store.php?page=1&search=football

please help really important I should fix this today.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could check `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` and if something is there, prepend it to your search form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Send `page` request in hidden format with the form, look at below code.

```
<form method="get" action="store.php">
   <input type="text" name='search' value="" placeholder="Enter Keyword to search" />
   <input type="hidden" name="page" value="1" />
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="search" />
</form>
```

this 
`<input type="hidden" name="page" value="1" />` will make your work done.

or

you can do one more way, if you are using ajax search, send query string manually by adding `page=1`

let's say you have query string `http://localhost/webstore/store.php?search=football` here add `page=1` manually.

You can do that concatenate with your query string using `+` sign in javascript or jQuery

Hope it will serve your purpose ;)

Comment: Thank you No am not using ajax search but I find my way to do it but your is also good maybe I will switch to it.